# jquery nyroModal just wont display my hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nyromodal

I have set up the DOM Element (hidden div) exmplae of nyroModal on my computer adding the js files and stylesheet but when I click the link to display the hidden div nothing seems to happen, can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html >
```

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/nyroModal.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nyroModal-ie6.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
    });
</script>
```

```
<a href="#test" class="nyroModal">DOM Element (hidden div)</a>

<div id="test" style="display: none; width: 600px;">
    <a href="demoSent.php" class="nyroModal">Open a new modal</a><br />
    Test
</div>
```

Comment: maybe because the link (a href) is also a nyroModal class? I guess you click the link 'DOM Element (hidden div)' link to show the div with the id of 'test'? With other modal frameworks you also had to specify which click makes the modal element show up. Don't you have to specify that the first link has to open the modal div?

Comment: this code snippet is taken from the http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/ site, I havent altered it at all?

Comment: hmm, didn't read your post correct, you used the example code, that should work indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `class="myroModal"` on the link, not the div. Or you need to change the `$('.nyroModal').nyroModal();` to be `$('.test').nyroModal();`

Comment: I updated the div to .myroModal and this didnt work I also changed .nyroModal in the script to #test and this didnt work either?

Comment: @kyllle If you downloaded the zip file from the website, the js file is named jquery.nyroModal.custom.js. Removing the .custom for me allowed your original code to work.

Comment: but thats exaactly what I did also, I noticed that there wasnt actually a file called .nyroModal.custom so I also removed the .custom, only thing is it just wont work for me?

Comment: @kylle I tried using chrome and ie, both seem to work for me. Using chrome helped me see the error via the developer tools. You might look at the console and see if there are any errors.